# Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class ?\?\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider does not exist

Tags: magento2

I have created my own extension in magento 2.3.X
But somehow magento says all my classes does not exist.

even I registered the extension after running the setup:upgrade
As I can I see it in enabled modules.

NB: I'm new to magento but I'm following the magento docs.

Comment: Can you post your code here? We're not going to be able to debug without seeing some of your files

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Confirm the following things.

1. You are created `all required file` of your extension.
2. Extension `install` properly into the system.
3. Extension `enable` into the system.

Comment: Sorry for being late, well I fixed the issue, the problem was in the php file was opened the wrong way instead of this **<?php** I found this **?php**  I don't know how it happend to be like this but this was the issue.